# how to ignore gradle dependency version in build.gradle config file

Tags: gradle

In maven we can write like this to make maven management version automatic:

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

how to write like this in gradle(6.0) to make gradle manage dependencies automatic?Is it possible

Comment: Given that your example is about spring boot, I would recommend following the spring boot gradle plugin documentation. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#introduction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add Spring Boot plugin. Next you can omit Spring versions in your code.

E.g. please add the following block into the top of your file (for Gradle KTS notation):

```
plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.2.2"
}
```